# Image CSS Masonry layout

Tags: css, masonry

I'm trying to do a CSS Masonry layout with images using the code below (which is within a foreach loop in PHP):

```
<div class="pagepix">
  <img alt="Testing 02" src="/images/thumbnail/image__xeKPEyHYPAnxsnKCWMKQ_1411534017.jpg">
  <img alt="Testing 01" src="/images/thumbnail/image__uVfmzTwGzakmClDShyDA_1411533981.jpg">
  <img alt="Testing 05" src="/images/thumbnail/image__WmLHwllUknhfDjocHqxn_1411533993.jpg">
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.pagepix{line-height:0;-webkit-column-count:2;-webkit-column-gap:0;-moz-column-count:2;-moz-column-gap:0;column-count:2;column-gap:0}
.pagepix img{width:100%;height:auto}
```

I was wondering if there was any way of doing it so it has two small images, then one large image underneath.. example

```
image     |     image

  full width image  

image     |     image

  full width image
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: then why do you want to use masonry? this is the anti-masonry layout by definition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the question i think masonry is not necessary just make two class

```
.halfimg{ width:50%; float:left;}

.fullimg{ width:100%;}

<div class="pagepix">
  <img class="halfimg" alt="Testing 02" src="/images/thumbnail/image__xeKPEyHYPAnxsnKCWMKQ_1411534017.jpg">
  <img class="halfimg"  alt="Testing 01" src="/images/thumbnail/image__uVfmzTwGzakmClDShyDA_1411533981.jpg">
  <img class="fullimg"  alt="Testing 05" src="/images/thumbnail/image__WmLHwllUknhfDjocHqxn_1411533993.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether Masonry is right choice for this but you ca n achieve it through CSS `float:left` OR you can use [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) OR [Foundation Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) OR [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) OR this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dimomohit/ksjef1y0/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend using this CSS code and their respective classes on HTML:

```
div.pagepix div.half{ 
    width:48%; 
    float:left;
    padding: 1%; // Change this to margin if you don't want them to be smaller
}

div.pagepix div.full{
    width:98%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%; // Change this to margin if you don't want them to be smaller
}

<div class="pagepix">
    <img class="half" alt="Testing 02" src="/images/thumbnail/image__xeKPEyHYPAnxsnKCWMKQ_1411534017.jpg">
    <img class="half"  alt="Testing 01" src="/images/thumbnail/image__uVfmzTwGzakmClDShyDA_1411533981.jpg">
    <img class="full"  alt="Testing 05" src="/images/thumbnail/image__WmLHwllUknhfDjocHqxn_1411533993.jpg">
</div>
```

You'll have some space between them and works fine.